# How to keep the radio button remain checked after the refresh

Tags: javascript, php

I've read few similar questions like mine and I've tried some of the option but still did not work for my code.

Basically I have radio button where I checked it by value=\"$Id\".
The reason why it refresh to the same page is because I want it to pass new total price once the user choose their address (* the shipping fee determined by the state).

```
echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"select\" value=\"$Id\" id=\"$State\"   onclick=\"test()\" > <label>$Name</label><br>";

<script>
function test(){
//got few lines of codes here
var tprice = document.getElementById("prices");
var user = document.getElementById("userid");

var b = document.querySelector('input[name="select"]:checked').value;

var tot= parseFloat(calc)+0;

var totals = parseFloat(calc) + parseFloat(tprice.value);
var userid = user.value;

window.location.href = "summary.php?tot=" + tot +"&totals="+ totals +"&userid="+ userid+"&idd="+b;


 document.getElementById(b).checked = true;
  </script>
```

Comment: You can do it in javascript or jQuery without refresh

Comment: Do you have singe radio button on that page or have multiple radio buttons that need to be checked every time the page refresh?

Comment: onle 1 radio button need to be checked.

Comment: @user9064942 see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can set values in session storage on select of radio. add `onclick="handleClick(this);"` inside radio button.

```
function handleClick(myRadio) {
  sessionStorage.setItem("data",JSON.stringify({"myRadioButtonId":"checked"}));
}
```

Now get data from local storage on document ready . And set checked attributes to that radio button.

```
 var data = sessionStorage.getItem('data');
 if(JSON.parse(data).myRadioButtonId == 'checked'){
   document.getElementById("myRadioButtonId").checked = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a radio button to be checked, you give it the attribute checked.

```
echo "<input type=\"radio\" " . $_GET['idd'] == $ID ? 'checked' : '' . " name=\"select\" value=\"$Id\" id=\"$State\"   onclick=\"test()\" > <label>$Name</label><br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use localstorage or sessionstorage, cookies, or best  option use php server session $_SESSION
surround your echo as form and submit onclick
`<form id="myForm" method="post" action="summary.php">`
`echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"select\" value=\"$Id\" id=\"$State\"   onclick=\"test()\" > <label>$Name</label><br>";`

`</form>`

`test() {
  // assign to value to hidden inputs
  //then submit the form
  document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}`